# Pressure at some different points with the same heights

Tags: pressure

Why do the red points in the following figure have the same pressure?
[image]

Comment: I know the formula $P=P_0 +\rho gh$, but I don't understand how it is possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/222949/pressure-in-fluids-at-a-height-depth

Comment: @FakeMod Thank you for the link, but I can't get my answer from it:(.

Comment: @M.Ramana, it's not a question of understanding how the pressure equation is possible.  It's an established fact, from measurements, that hydrostatic pressure depends ONLY on vertical depth, and is independent of horizontal location.

Comment: @DavidWhite You're right. I understood. This was an interesting fact for me. I thought there was a proof for it like mathematical problems. Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: @M.Ramana, there is a subtle distinction that I will try to make.  Physics is not math.  Math is used to model a given physical phenomenon, and most (or all) mathematical models only approximate the physical phenomenon to varying degrees, depending on the needs of the person developing the model.  This means that math is the language of physics, but the physics drives the math rather than the math driving the physics.

Comment: @DavidWhite That's right. I'm a math student and I thought every physical phenomenon, after measurements, must be proved like a theorem in math. So I was trying to prove the fact above mathematically. I was in wrong. Thank you for your good explanation. I understood the distinction between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pressure, in an open container such as this, only depends on depth. The red dots are all at the same depth from the surface. They all have the same height of water above them. Water pressure increases about 1.47 psi per meter of depth, regardless of the shape of the container.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I understood completely.